# Problems running UiAutomator2 on Android 7.0

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I'm developing my UITests in Espresso but in order to be able to click in the Google Auth dialog, I'm using UIAutomator.

I'm running the tests on an Android 8.0 and all works fine, but when I ran it on an Android 7.0 the test don't work properly.

This is the line where the test gets freezed:

```
UiObject mText = mUiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().textContains(BuildConfig.BASE_EMAIL));
```

I tried it with another 8.0 Android device and a 9.0, and all works well.

Comment: what's the error that you are seeing?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. The test gets freezed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some difference between resource ID of `Google Auth dialog` in `Android 7` and other higher APIs. Can you double check if the `resource IDs` are same or not using `uiautomatorviewer` generally present at

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

Open `uiautomator` using `command prompt` of the system.

Comment: Both resource-id are com.google.android.gms:id/account_name.

Comment: a possibility could be that when your code is too fast than actual UI in nougat to click the view. You can put Thread.sleep(3000) before clicking view in Nougat.

Comment: That's not the problem as I added a sleep the first time I wrote the test.

Comment: set a break point in that line of code but execute the line in expression evaluator window or try wrapping the code in try/catch. It would be great if you can fetch exact error.